# Is it grammatically incorrect if I use "be" instead of "are" in the following passage?

Tags: grammar

> It is inevitable that their decisions are final.

I'm not sure if "inevitable" is a subjunctive adjective and if we can use "be" instead of "are" in the sentence above.

Comment: The 2 variants don’t quite say the same thing. What is the intended meaning?

Comment: @Lawrence, The intended meaning is that the finality of their decision is inevitable. How are the two variants different?

Comment: Don't you mean *will be*?

Comment: @tchrist, No, I mean just "be". Grammatically speaking, the subjunctive form of most verbs is simply the base form of the verb: "It is recommended that she prepare a short speech before the ceremony." Now, I don't know if "inevitable" can be a subjunctive adjective.

Comment: The use of "be" I believe you have in mind is the one in which something is essential and must be ensured, not one where it is inevitable. For example we do say things like "It is _vital_ that their decisions _be_ final". If something is inevitable there is no need to ensure that it happens so _be_ is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

As a UK English speaker, I don't think 'be' in this context is grammatical. When you render the likes of "It's important that you be here" you are referring to the future (in which case you're using the subjunctive to describe future actions) and if you are going to use that particular phrasing, I would say it would be wrong not to use the subjunctive. However, the phrase "It is inevitable that their decisions are final" is NOT expressing [suggestions, wishes or desires](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/getting-in-the-subjunctive-mood#:%7E:text=The%20subjunctive%20mood%20is%20one,then%20with%20a%20subjunctive%20verb.&text=In%20a%20sentence%20like%20%22I,verb%20be%20undergoes%20a%20change.). And also, I would like to argue that the subjunctive mood has fallen into disuse and doesn't sound totally smooth or natural.

Answer (score 1):

"Are" is better than "be".

Forms such as "It's essential that he be here" are known as the mandative subjunctive (see Wikipedia's article on the [English subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive)). They express commands or orders (sometimes recommendations): you are saying "I order that he be here." I suspect the OP is thinking of cases like this. If you're merely stating something you would use the non-subjunctive verb. "It's essential that he is here" means it's necessary, as a fact, but isn't commanding he be brought there. Likewise, "It is inevitable that their decisions are final" isn't really a command, just a statement of fact, so no subjunctive.

There are various other uses of the subjunctive, of varying degrees of popularity in contemporary English, but generally with conditionals or other forms of command ("God save the queen", etc). That doesn't apply here either.

Comment: If the OP wanted to use the mandative subjunctive, another adverb might help. For example, "It is *imperative* that their decisions be final" follows this form.

Comment: @RobJarvis, "Imperative" is an adjective, not an adverb.

Comment: Sorry, @BeatsMe, you caught me asleep at the wheel.